# How to compile a delphi application through command line (silent mode) which uses third party components?

Tags: delphi

I have a delphi application which uses multiple 3rd party components like DevExpress, TeeChart, etc.. I want to compile this (to make a automatic build) through command line. How can I achieve this?

Expecting a Delphi application to compile/build via command prompt.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you really using all these Delphi versions you tagged your question with?

Comment: dcc32 has an option to specify (your own and third party source code) directories   `-U<paths> = Unit directories`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how it can be done in Delphi 7, but in recent versions of Delphi it's easy.

1. You must prepare Project Group with all that you need to compile
2. Make BAT file that will compile this project group by msbuild
3. Call this BAT when you need to compile.

Detail's of making BAT file:

First of all you need to have all necessary environment variables in context of BAT file.
Standard Delphi environment variables stored in "rsvars.bat"-file in Delphi directory 
(for Delphi 11 it's "c:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\bin\rsvars.bat")
So, to have it in your context just use BAT-command:

```
call "c:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\bin\rsvars.bat"
```

if you need to specify some other environment variables witches need to be specified to compile your packages or projects, you can do it in a same way as it done in rsvars.bat

After that step - msbuild can find Delphi compiler to run building. So, you can just call:

```
msbuild ".\MyProjectGroup.groupproj"
```

That all you need to compile projects with default params.

Sure, you can customize compiler params, so my command line looks like:

```
msbuild ".\MyProjectGroup.groupproj"  /t:%BuildMode% /l:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;logfile=MyProjectGroup_%PlatformMode%_%ConfigMode%.log;verbosity=quiet /p:Config=%ConfigMode% /p:platform=%PlatformMode%
```

where: 
%BuildMode% - can be Build, Clean, Make
%ConfigMode% - Debug or Release
%PlatformMode% - Win32 or Win64

For more information look at official [Doc](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Building_a_Project_Using_an_MSBuild_Command)

P.S. Last version of Delphi Community Edition does not support command line compiling.

Comment: This won't work for Delphi 7 (or any Delphi version < 2007) as they don't use msbuild.

Comment: @dummzeuch Yea, i know. I wrote this answer, because question is marked also for delphi-xe2, delphi-2010, delphi-xe

Comment: A project group is not needed if it is a single application (Program.dpr).

Comment: @mjn Yes, your are right., *.dproj files can be compiled without project group, but author wrote about lot of 3-rd part components, so i decide to explain how to compile this all at one time.

Comment: Additional dpr or dproj files are not needed to compile any third party units into the application.

Comment: @mjn That's not really always true. It's depends how you project are configurated. If you use option "Link runtime packages" or you include into search path only folder with dcu, dcp, etc(not pas) in that case your project can compile with not relevant version of 3rd part components.

Answer (score 0):

The Delphi Wiki says the following regarding [command line compilation with Delphi 1-7](https://delphi.fandom.com/wiki/Compile_from_Commandline):

> In these Delphi versions each project consisted of a
> .dpr file which contained a uses-list of all the
> project's units and the main program, a .dof file which
> in .ini file format contained all the project's
> settings, e.g. the compiler switches and the search
> paths. In addition the IDE created a .cfg file which
> contained the settings in a different format, suitable
> for the commandline compiler.
>
> As long as you are content to just use the same settings
> as in the IDE you can just call
>
> dcc32 [project].dpr
>
> and the commandline compiler will compile your project,
> using the settings from the .cfg file.
>
> If you do not want to rely on the IDE to create the .cfg
> file, there is this dof2cfg tool
>
> If you are using project groups (.bpg), you could also
> use the borland make tool because a .bpg file had the
> format of a make file for this tool.

I wrote that article many years ago, so I am sure it is correct. But I haven't used Delphi 7 for several years.

Answer (score 0):

The Delphi compiler has an option to specify your (including third party) unit directories:

```
-U<paths> = Unit directories
```